Java 17 Fork join pool limit number of threads in pool
In java 17, we are seeing that a lot more threads are getting created (although not concurrently executing) as compared to older java version (java 8 in my case). While thread itself may not be a huge problem, In each thread DB connection is being made, hence we end up breaking the max concurrent session limit by our DB client.
public class TestForkJoin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        System.out.println(a.fetchAll(Collections.singleton("ok")));
    }

    public abstract static class Base {
        public Map<String, String> fetchAll(Set<String> ids) {
            return ids.stream().parallel().map(i -> ImmutablePair.of(i, fetch(i))).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
        }

        public abstract String fetch(String id);
    }

    public static class ClassA extends Base {

        @Override
        public String fetch(String id) {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            Map<String, String> result = b.fetchAll(Collections.singleton(id));
            return String.join(":", result.values());
        }
    }

    public static class ClassB extends Base {

        @Override
        public String fetch(String id) {
            return id;
        }
    }
}

In the above example we are recursively calling .parallel(). For example
A.fetchAll() -> .parallel()  -> A.fetch() -> B.fetchAll() -> .parallel(). 

To Deep dive on this. .parallel() uses forkJoinPool.commonpool() whose parallelism is controlled by number of cores on the machine or java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism.
In java 8, i was seeing that only 8 thread were concurrently executing and the pool size was also 8. but In java17, event though parallelism is 8, the pool size goes upto 150. Below are some of the option i evaluated

Not using fork join pool but use executor service with fixed core pool size
But this option does not work for us, because if more number of concurrent request comes on classA.fetchAll, then the threads would get in deadlock state. In fact this is one the of the primary advantage of using fork join pool over executor service. see here

Instead of using forkjoin common pool, use custom fork join pool with limit on pool size
Whenever the pool size limit is reached exception is thrown. So this practically does not solve anything.
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Thread limit exceeded replacing blocked worker



Basically I want, infinite size queue, but number of threads in pool should not increase.
This openjdk issues seems to be related to this.

The problem mentioned in step #2 seems like this question, and there is a workaround.

maybe according documentation of ForkJoinPool: "The parameters used to construct the common pool may be controlled by setting the following system properties: . . . java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.maximumSpares - the maximum number of allowed extra threads to maintain target parallelism (default 256)." ?

I am not certain you can bound the number of threads without risking deadlock.

if more tasks are submitted than parallelism + maximumSpares, it results in exception while submitting the task.

I was not able to reproduce the issue on local, because i was trying to reproduce using Thread.sleep() but Thread.sleep is a graceful way to tell that thread wants to sleep. Rather than doing thread.sleep I started making http call.
As @DuncG suggested in comment using maximumPoolSize, along with saturation predicate fixed the issue. Set maximumPoolSize equals to number of connections we can afford. And always return saturated = true in the predicate.
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test2 {

    private static final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4, ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, false, 0, 10, 1, pool -> {
        boolean allow = true;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " saturate:" + allow);
        return allow;
    }, 3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logPoolStats();
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        System.out.println(a.fetchAll(IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }


    public abstract static class Base {
        public Map<String, String> fetchAll(List<String> ids) {
            List<Callable<ImmutablePair<String, String>>> todo = new ArrayList<>();
            ids.forEach(id -> todo.add(() -> ImmutablePair.of(id, fetch(id))));

            List<Future<ImmutablePair<String, String>>> futures = forkJoinPool.invokeAll(todo);

            return futures.stream().map(i -> {
                try {
                    return i.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
        }

        public abstract String fetch(String id) throws IOException, InterruptedException;
    }

    public static class ClassA extends Base {

        @Override
        public String fetch(String id) {
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            Map<String, String> result = b.fetchAll(IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            return String.join(":", result.values());
        }
    }

    public static class ClassB extends Base {
        @Override
        public String fetch(String id) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                HttpClient.newBuilder().build().send(HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://stackoverflow.com/" + id)).build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
            return "ok";
        }
    }


    private static void logPoolStats() {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("active.threads " + forkJoinPool.getActiveThreadCount());
                System.out.println("running.threads " + forkJoinPool.getRunningThreadCount());
                System.out.println("pool.size " + forkJoinPool.getPoolSize());
                System.out.println("queue.submission " + forkJoinPool.getQueuedSubmissionCount());
                System.out.println("parallelism " + forkJoinPool.getParallelism());
                System.out.println("queue.task " + forkJoinPool.getQueuedTaskCount());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}



Just ran into the same issue. Your solution was the only way to set an upper bound of parallel executions.

From the text below I understand that in Java 17 there are more threads in a threadpool than in the java versions used before. As every thread connects to the database separately there are too many parallel database connections and the application has problems.
With parallel stream processing (.stream().parallel()) you do not control how many threads will be working on the problem. Instead you could use an Executor to have better control.
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); // assuming five threads is your limit
A.fetchAll().stream().forEach(a -> {
   es.submit(new Runnable(){
       B.fetchAll().stream().forEach(b -> {
           es.submit(new Runnable() {
               // do the real work
           });
       });
   });
}

In this case you definitely know that never more than 5 threads are executing - even the nested task of building the queue is run from within these five threads.
If you prefer to run more threads in parallel but realize that the threads do not need to hog a DB connection each, make use of a DB Connection Pool. The pattern in you logic should then be to process as much as possible, grab a DB connection, run the necessary query and release that connection (back to the pool) as soon as possible. Check out https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

while you have understood the problem well, using fixedThreadpool with recursive calls results into bottleneck, because running threads are not stolen till thread's execution completes. This is one crucial difference between forkjoin and executorService.

What do you mean by 'running threads are not stolen till thread's execution completes'? It is the ThreadPool that manages the threads. I edited my answer.

the solution works as long as recursive calls are not happening. but if recursive calls in method are happen, as par example in question, this breaks.

Does this recursion require that the caller collects the results? While waiting for the callee, the caller can free up it's DB connection. Looks like you can very well use DBCP.

yes, some of the client pool might be efficient in connection useage. but in my case we were using aerospike java client. And connection were not getting reused even though only 8 threads were running. It led me to believe other threads in thread pool are holding connections.

Hmmm. A non-JDBC driver will not allow the classic connection pools to be applied. You may even be looking at a memory leak problem. I suggest you run heap analysis when the problem reappears.
